# Cast a website to Google Chromecast

Tags: javascript, chromecast

Normally you stream a video or music or something similar to Google ChromeCast.

But I don't have a video. I have a presentation based on HTML, CSS and JavaScript which I want to show on a ChromeCast.

Is there a way to just view a website with the Chromecast-SDK or is it possible to simulate a video-stream depending on a website?

Comment: `right click` > `cast...`

Comment: Where is the right click function in the Google Cast SDK.......

Comment: In chrome, right click somewhere on the page and there is a context menu option to cast the page as is